# approach custom module userlogin via ajax

Tags: 7, ajax, users, forms

for several reasons I try to develop my own module in order to have a fully customizable user login via ajax. Later on I will integrate this in a modalbox.

I already wrote the basics of the module, the form, as well as a js-file. But I don't know how to go on from here. Concrete questions:

- How to login the user in case of success instantly without making a full new http request(asynchron)?
- How to validate without reload?
- How to fire certain js events in case of login success?
- How to improve my existing code?

Enviroment: D7, with plain and unedited starter theme called framework, Devel is the only module I installed.

Thanks in advance, existing code follows right here:

```
<?php 



function ajaxforms_page_build(&$page) {
// drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ajaxforms') . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 20));
// drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ajaxforms') . '/js/additional-methods.min.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 20));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ajaxforms') . '/js/ajaxforms.js', array( 'scope' => 'footer', 'group' => JS_THEME, 'weight' => 20));
}

function ajaxforms_menu() {

$items['ajaxforms'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ajax Login',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('ajaxforms_basic'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
return $items;

} 


function ajaxforms_basic($form, &$form_state) {


$form = array();

$form['username'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Nutzername'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

$form['password'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Passwort'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

if(isset($form_state['values']['username'])) {
    $form['password']['#description'] = 'Test ' . $form_state['values']['username'];
}

$form['password']['#prefix'] = '<div id="ajaxforms-basic-wrapper"></div>';
// $form['password']['#suffix'] = '</div>';


$form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Login'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajaxforms_user_login_credentials_user',
    'wrapper' => 'ajaxforms-basic-wrapper')
    );

return $form; 
}

function ajaxform_basic_validate($form, &$form_state) {
if ($form_state['values']['username'] == 'KingKong'):
    form_set_error('username', t('FALSCHER NUTZER'));
endif;
 };

function ajaxform_basic_callback($form, &$form_state) {
dpm($form_state);

if ($uid = user_authenticate($username, $password)) {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($uid);

  $login_array = array ('name' => $username);
  user_login_finalize($login_array);
  drupal_session_regenerate();
}

return dpm($form);
}
```

And the js:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.Ajaxforms = {
attach: function(context, settings) {
    var message_field = $('#ajaxforms-basic-wrapper');
    $("#edit-submit", context).once(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
        var user = $('#edit-username').val();
        var pass = $('#edit-password').val();
        var error = 0;
        // if (user=="") {
        //   message_field.html("Bitte geben Sie einen Nutzernamen ein");
        //   error++;
        // }

        // if (pass=="") {
        //   message_field.html("Bitte geben Sie einen Passwort ein");
        //   error++;
        // }


            $.ajax({
                  url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'ajaxforms/user-login',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {
                    username: user,/** Pass the User Name **/
                    password: pass/** Pass the Password **/
                  },
                  success: function(response) {
                    message_field.html(response);
                    Drupal.attachBehaviors();
                  }
            });
        });
    });
}
};

 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: You're re-inventing the wheel here - https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register. If you absolutely must roll your own version, just copy the code from there

Comment: Thanks for your tip, that I will check immediately, but since i'm new Drupal at all, I see this is as practice to get a better understanding of Drupal. So if you can give me a short outline of a solution I would be very happy.